# Websphere 8.5- Application cannot get image from symlink

Tags: websphere-8

I have installed Websphere 8.5 and update to Websphere 8.5.5.4, OS: Redhat 6.3
I have installed Application is apptest.war
I have created symlink in folder apptest.war link to Folder on system:

```
ln -s POSImage /Images
```

I checked permission folder POSImage and /Images full permission
when I get image in folder /POSImage by URL below show error:

http://192.168.5.4:9080/apptest/POSImages/POS_543956_1425272116854_picture1.jpg

> Error 404: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /POSImages/POS_543956_1425272116854_picture1.jpg

but upload images from Application to Folder POSimage is good.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert by any means, but I have been doing some very similar stuff recently myself.  I have a few things to say that MAY help.

- 1:  When I do my link creation, I do the creating in he directory in which I want the link created.
- 2:  I also use the full path for the link.  So, the syntax looks like:

  > ln -s /full/path/to/file/or/directory linkName
- 3:  Finally, I do not include the / that I see in your syntax (/Images).